# K6 - measure average response time across all vus for a certain request out of group of requests

Tags: performance-testing, reporting, k6

Hi I would like to measure the avg, highest response time of one specific request in a group of requests across all vus.

Can you please advice how to do that?

I can see the request in the results of the cloud run. There I can see the average time and all I need, but how do I get this kind of result and just that as a result of the test, e.g. when I run it locally through command line.

[image: Cloud Result]

I found this here while playing around, so I can log what I consider the actual execution time of this request

response.timings.duration.toLocaleString()

I could accumulate these values and determine average and max, but is this the right and/or only way?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, can you clarify? `k6` on the local CLI already prints an [end of test summary](https://k6.io/docs/results-output/end-of-test/) which contains the metric values for all http requests (avg, min, max, median, p(90), p(95)). As long as the requests are properly tagged, they should be displayed as separate lines in the summary. What information is lacking from the summary?

Comment: @knittl Then the actual question would be, how do I tag the request so that I can see it as an extra line in the summary? Because right now I only see the avg request time across all requests.

Comment: But in the cloud GUI I can see the request time for this specific request without tagging it.

Comment: Found it https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/tags-and-groups/

Answer (score 1):

To group request metrics and have them printed as separate line in the summary, use [tags](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/tags-and-groups/). Make sure to define [thresholds on your tags](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/thresholds/#thresholds-on-tags)

For example, to group 4 requests by 2 tag values:

```
import http from 'k6/http';

export const options = {
  thresholds: {
    'http_req_duration{mygroup:A}': [],
    'http_req_duration{mygroup:B}': [],
  },
};

export default function () {
  http.get('http://httpbin.test.k6.io/', { tags: { mygroup: 'A' } });
  http.get('http://httpbin.test.k6.io/', { tags: { mygroup: 'B' } });
  http.get('http://httpbin.test.k6.io/', { tags: { mygroup: 'B' } });
  http.get('http://httpbin.test.k6.io/', { tags: { mygroup: 'A' } });
}
```

Will give you metrics of the form:

```
 http_req_duration..............: avg=179.3ms  min=108.38ms med=198.85ms max=307.7ms  p(90)=207.49ms p(95)=234.25ms
   { expected_response:true }...: avg=179.3ms  min=108.38ms med=198.85ms max=307.7ms  p(90)=207.49ms p(95)=234.25ms
   { mygroup:A }................: avg=166.47ms min=108.38ms med=191.7ms  max=204.91ms p(90)=204.69ms p(95)=204.8ms 
   { mygroup:B }................: avg=192.12ms min=108.71ms med=204.29ms max=307.7ms  p(90)=239.15ms p(95)=273.42ms
```

This will work for the [cloud runner as well](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/tags-and-groups/#tags-and-groups-in-k6-cloud-results).